# ArrayStoreException when trying to collect files into array via Files.walk

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I am trying to understand the Java 8 Stream-feature.

I would like to catch all files in an array (could als be list) in all subdirectories of a specific directory path.

My code throws an java.lang.ArrayStoreException Error

> ```
>   File[] files = Files.walk(Paths.get(path))
>       .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
>       .toArray(File[]::new);
> ```

Another thing I tried is just add the file names to an existing ArrayList:

> ```
>   ArrayList<String> existingNames = new ArrayList<String>();
>   Files.walk(Paths.get(path))
>       .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
>       .forEach(p -> existingNames.add(p.getFileName()));
> ```

This throws a java.lang.ArrayStoreException Error as well.

Something else I tried with the same result was:

> ```
>   File[] files = Files.walk(Paths.get(path))
>       .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
>       .toArray(File[]::new);
> ```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

The full stack trace is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException  at
>   java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)     at
>   java.util.stream.SpinedBuffer.copyInto(SpinedBuffer.java:198)     at
>   java.util.stream.Nodes$SpinedNodeBuilder.copyInto(Nodes.java:1290)    at
>   java.util.stream.SpinedBuffer.asArray(SpinedBuffer.java:215)  at
>   java.util.stream.Nodes$SpinedNodeBuilder.asArray(Nodes.java:1296)     at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:439)
>     at
>   nachbearbeitung.CheckExistingMAIDs.main(CheckExistingMAIDs.java:41)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share the full stacktrace please?

Comment: My bad! Thanks for the hint. It is a java.lang.ArrayStoreException Error

Comment: This may be a duplicate of [Dealing with an ArrayStoreException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12369957/dealing-with-an-arraystoreexception). Unfortunately, I've never seen this error before, so I can't help with it beyond that link.

Comment: Here is the documentation of Files.walk: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walk-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-. It returns a Stream<Path>. You're trying to store these Paths into an Array of Files. So that can't work. Bananas go in banana boxes. Eggs go in egg boxes. Same here.

Comment: Thanks JB. That did the trick. From the Path-Object, you can get the FileName, but that's still a Path Object. To get the String you have to add .toString().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `ArrayStoreException` is not specific to Java streams, it's very old Java Exception which means that you want to store an element of incompatible type inside an array. In your case you want to create an array of `File` objects. But in fact you are trying to store `Path` objects there, as `Files.walk` produces a `Stream<Path>`, not `Stream<File>`. To convert a `Path` to a `File` you may use `Path.toFile` method calling it in the `map` step:

```
File[] files = Files.walk(Paths.get("."))
        .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
        .map(Path::toFile)
        .toArray(File[]::new);
```

Answer (score 2):

To list only file names:

```
List<Path> pathList = Files.walk(Paths.get(path))
                           .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());

pathList.forEach(p -> System.out.println(p.getFileName()));
```

Can't store a method's local variable in a Stream:  `.forEach(p -> existingNames.add(p.getFileName()));`