# com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics cannot be stored in an array of type io.fabric.sdk.android.Kit[]

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

Crashlytics `compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9@aar')` is integrated with the app, The crash is seen from application onCreate method and following stacktrace is obtained. No other similar error/explaination could be found on stackoverflow. Any suggestions are welcome.

**Error:**

> Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics cannot be stored in an array of type io.fabric.sdk.android.Kit[]
>           at com.sobersystems.mobile_managed.SoberSplash.onCreate(SoberSplash.java:39)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)

Comment: Can you please post your initialization code of Crashlytics ?

Comment: buildscript {
    ......

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}


dependencies {
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
|

Comment: Initialisation Code means the code that has been written in your SoberSplash activity to initialise your Crashlytics. Particularly, at line number 39.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dealing with an ArrayStoreException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12369957/dealing-with-an-arraystoreexception)

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. As Chintan noted, having the init code from your application's subclassed onCreate where you add Fabric is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you are having the Crashlytics.jar in your **libs** **directory** and compile Crashlytics in **build.gradle**. 
Remove any one, hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Perform a clean.  You possibly changed build types and made a change to your gradle build file and got things out of whack.

Build-->Clean Project